# Getting a function out of binary sequences (symbolic dynamics). Inverse problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, inverse-problems

So this is the tent map:

$$
  T(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    2x & \text{if $x<0.5$} \\
    2-2x & \text{if $x \geq 0.5$} 
  \end{cases}
$$

if we take any ponit $x_0 \in [0,1]$ then $T(x_0) \in [0,1]$ so we can construct it's orbit $O(x_0) = (x_0,T(x_0),T^2(x_0),T^3(x_0),...)$ then we can take it into a binary using the rule if $x_{0}^{n} \rightarrow 0$ if $x_{0}^{n} < 0.5$ and $x_{0}^{n} \rightarrow 1$ if $x_{0}^{n} \geq 0.5$
where $x_{0}^{n} = T^n(x_0)$ for example:

$$(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.4,...)\longrightarrow (0,0,0,1,0,1,0,...)$$
$$(0.64,0.72,0.56,0.88,0.24,0.48,0.96,...)\longrightarrow (1,1,1,1,0,0,1,...) $$

What I'm wondering is something like the inverse, if a have a set of binary sequences is there a way in which I can get a function like the tent map that generates these sequences? I don't think it's posible to do it this generally or that they might be many, but are there a set of conditions which could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible because you have lost information in every rounding step.  A pure information-theoretic argument proves that.

Comment: I am not sure if I get you correctly on the lossing information part? Do you mean because of 1st order markov chain or something else? And about the theoretical proves, can you tell me where I can find more informaion?

Comment: You lose information whenever multiple "inputs" are mapped to the same output (the many-to-one case)... for example, if any number in the range $[0.5,1]$ gets mapped to $1$.  Given the output $1$, there is no way you can ever recover the input... (was it 0.537?  0.972?  0.881?, ...).  In short, you have "lost information."  You *wouldn't* lose information in the one-to-one case, however.